# Can a question about Windows SSH clients find a more appropriate site to live on?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[Windows CLI SSH client?](https://superuser.com/questions/471786/windows-cli-ssh-client) seems to be bringing in a fair amount of users.

It would be a shame to let all those people ending up there via Google search results hit a 404.

Can this question be moved/forwarded to a better place than Super User?

Answer (score 3):

It's too old to migrate. For those who can't see it, it's a post from 2012.

Only posts [within the past 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) can be migrated.

You are more than free to ask on another SE site, such as [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), assuming it's [not a duplicate there](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=windows+ssh+is%3Aq).